# Orange Pi Armbian no network

Tags: networking, armbian

I have installed armbian on SD card and I cannot get no network. Neither ethernet, neither wireless.
Only thing I managed is to connect to it via serial port.
Here is some information about my network im connected to:

```
Gateway: 192.168.8.1
Dhcp: 192.168.8.1
DNS: 192.168.8.1
```

Network DNS always assigns addresses from 100-200

```
root@orangepizero:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         -               255.255.255.0   !     0      -        0 -
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

root@orangepizero:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp
 gateway 192.168.8.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlan0
 iface wlan0 inet dhcp
 wpa-ssid *****
 wpa-psk *****
```

I have tried assigning static addresses, and some other tips I found on the internet, and I had no success. Device is still without connection.

Here is my current ifconfig eth0 (although it has ip that I placed, it is not connected to the router)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e6:f5:19:a6:1b:e6
          inet addr:192.168.8.121  Bcast:192.168.8.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e4f5:19ff:fea6:1be6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:237 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:10602 (10.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:114
```

Comment: What dhcp client are you using? dhcpcd or isc-dhcp-client ?

Answer (score 0):

Your route is wrong. It should look something like this:

```
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
 0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     255.255.255.0   UG    600    0      0   eth0
```

Check your DHCP settings. The `gateway` and `netmask` settings are ignored when using the `dhcp` setting.

Comment: No success there. Here is my current route:

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.8.1     255.255.255.0   UG    600    0        0 eth0
192.168.8.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0`

Comment: Ok, now the default route looks ok, but you have changed the second route to a host route, which is not necessary. You should have two entries:
`default 192.168.8.1 255.255.255.0 UG 600 0 0 eth0

192.168.8.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 600 0 0 eth0`